# Uploaded image is messed up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I have a website that is a gallery so basically admin can upload an image with some information about that image and it'll be shown in the gallery, the problem is that when I upload an image with the size of ~40 KB, it works just fine, but when I upload another image with the size of ~230 KB, it looks it takes for ever to process the matter although the chrome  bottom status bar shows the % of the uploading file up to 100% percent but after that it keeps waiting for my server and it never ends... and the uploaded image is like http://www.atrin-gallery.ir/Images/Upload/dalangV.jpg

my code to handle file uploading is as below:

```
if (Request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["image"];

                if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    string subPath = "~/Images/Upload"; // your code goes here

                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

                    if (!isExists)
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
                    }

                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(subPath), fileName);
                    string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

P.S: I've been using the same function in many of my other websites and they just work fine with even bigger files or images, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you converting `ContentLength` to an int when its already an int?

Comment: yea good point but still that doesn't help with the main problem...removing that Convert.ToInt32 anyway.

Comment: open the image in a raw data viewer like emacs.  Compare the bad image to the good image.  Is there a bunch of junk characters at the end?  In the middle?  If you re-upload, is the problem always in the same place, or does it vary?

Comment: Try removing following lines;
string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength); and use just `file.SaveAs(path);`.

Comment: @RussellUhl no there's no bunch of junk characters at the end or the middle, and the gray part is always at the bottom, the middle is messed up, and the top is fine

Comment: @Saranga thanks Saranga, it fixed the problem as I tried 3 times and it worked fine, care to explain why those lines were causing the problem in a new replay so I can accept it as an answer? cheers

Comment: I don't know your scenario, but letting the client naming a file on your system isn't the best of ideas.

Comment: @Hylaean that's true, I'll fix that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove following lines from your code and use just `file.SaveAs(path);` to save the file.

```
string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
```

You don't need to read the `Stream` and if you try to read using `Read` method it will advance the position within the stream by the number of bytes read. ([Stream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Thanks!